# Which port and ip addresses are used while installing new ubuntu system

Tags: networking, system-installation, software-installation

As we know that when, we install the new Ubuntu system and if we are connected to the internet then it can fetches packages from Ubuntu repository.

So I have question which port and ip address is used while fetching those packages.

Answer (score 3):

You may view which servers will be queried by taking a look at `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Your computer will query a DNS server (port 53) for each of these domain names.  After the DNS has been resolved, your computer will access via whatever protocol is mentioned in the `sources.list` file.  Typically, this is HTTP (port 80).

By default, your computer will query the servers, and then you will be redirected to another mirror (based on round-robin or possibly geo-location) and your computer will download the latest information.

When you download information from the servers, or you download packages from the servers, all the data downloaded is verified using GPG/PGP verification.  This way, you can trust the packages from any server from which you download them.